# If $\alpha + \beta=\dfrac {\pi}{2}$ and $\beta + \phi=\alpha $ then $\tan \alpha$ equals.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

If $\alpha + \beta=\dfrac {\pi}{2}$ and $\beta + \phi=\alpha $ then $\tan \alpha$ equals.

$1$. $2\tan \beta + 2\tan \phi$

$2$. $\tan \beta + \tan \alpha $

$3$. $\tan \beta + 2\tan \phi $

$4$. $2\tan \beta. \tan \phi $

My Attempt:

$$\alpha +\beta =\dfrac {\pi}{2}$$
Taking $\tan $ on both sides,
$$\tan (\alpha +\beta )= \tan \dfrac {\pi}{2}$$
$$\tan (\alpha + \beta )=\infty $$

How do I proceed further?

Comment: Is your question really asking for $\tan\alpha$ in terms of $\tan \alpha$ (see option $2.$)

Comment: @TheDeadLegend, Yeah. The options are correctly typed as given.

Comment: only one of the answers passes the test of $\alpha = \beta=\frac \pi 4;\phi=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\beta = \frac {\pi}{2}-\alpha\\
\phi = \alpha - \beta$

$\tan \beta = \tan (\frac {\pi}{2}-\alpha) = \cot \alpha\\
\tan \phi = \frac {\tan\alpha - \tan\beta}{1+\tan \alpha\tan\beta} = \frac {\tan\alpha - \tan\beta}{2}$

$2\tan \phi + \tan\beta = \tan \alpha$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$\tan(\alpha+\beta)=\frac{\tan\alpha+\tan\beta}{1-\tan\alpha\tan\beta}=\frac{A}{0}$$
$$1-\tan\alpha\tan\beta=0$$

hope you can handle ahead of it?

Comment: Is $\tan \alpha=\tan \phi+\tan \beta$ correct?